# SQL variables are not working in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In my query, I need to get the previous row with the current row and then join a few tables. I got the previous row by using SQL variables in my development server(MySQL 5.7), everything works fine, but in my production(MariaDB 10) server that previous row results are bad just mixed, bad part is only that previous row with SQL variables other query parts works good.

My query:

```
                                  customers.title,
                                  calendar.start_time, 
                                  calendar.hours_per_time,
                                  calendar.self_certification,
                                  calendar.bulletin_certification,
                                  calendar.extra,
                                  @previous_start AS previous_start,
                                  @previous_start := calendar.start_time,
                                  @previous_end AS previous_end,
                                  @previous_end := calendar.hours_per_time,
                                  DATE_FORMAT(calendar.date, '%d-%m') AS day_month,
                                  TIME_FORMAT(calendar.start_time, '%H:%i') AS hours_min

        FROM
          (SELECT @previous_start := '00:00', @previous_end := '0.00') AS calendar_prev, calendar

            INNER JOIN relationships ON calendar.relation_id = relationships.relation_id
            INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = relationships.customer_id
            WHERE relationships.user_id = '$user_id'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(calendar.date, '%m-%Y') = '$date'
        ORDER BY calendar.date, hours_min ASC
```

Comment: Here's the thing: MySQL makes no guarantees about the order of execution of the select statement.  So while you expect those session variable statements to happen in a certain order, that might not be the case, and you could see different behaviors on different versions of MySQL.

Comment: If you have MariaDB 10.2, use its "Windowing" functions to deal with "previous" and "current" rows.